# How to store an UIButton image in UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I am new to IOS, I have a UITableview in that having three buttons, when I select the button image will change. my problem is: how to store the image in the table view, when I quit the app and again come back to the app means selected image should be there. how can I do this process can any one help me.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
CustomizedCellView *cell = (CustomizedCellView *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell = [table dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomizedCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 27, 36, 36);
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"l"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lblue.png"]
             forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn4:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    button1.tag=1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];
button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(160, 27, 36, 36);
    [button2 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"e"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"eblue.png"]
             forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn4:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button2];
    button2.tag=3;


    button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button3.frame = CGRectMake(240, 27, 36, 36);
    [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"v"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vblue.png"]
             forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn4:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button3];
    button3.tag=2;

- (void)radiobtn4:(UIButton *)sender

{
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview;
    if(sender.selected == NO)
    {

        if(sender.tag==1){

            UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            otherButton.selected=YES;
            UIButton *other=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
            other.selected=NO;

        }else if(sender.tag==2){
            UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
            otherButton.selected=YES;
            UIButton *other=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            other.selected=NO;


        } else if(sender.tag == 3)
        {
            UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
            otherButton.selected=YES;

        }

    } else  if(sender.selected == YES)

    {
        if(sender.tag==1){
            UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            [otherButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"l.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            otherButton.selected=NO;


        }else if(sender.tag==2){
            UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
            [otherButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"v.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            otherButton.selected=NO;

        }  else if(sender.tag == 3)
        {
            UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
            [otherButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"e.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            otherButton.selected=NO;

        }

    }

}
```

above is my coding.

Comment: Use database or, plist to store your selections..

Comment: main flag in array/dictionary you are passing/using

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSUserDefaults`

Storing:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageName forKey:@"selected_image"];
```

Retrieving:

```
NSString *imageName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"selected_image"];
```

***Later Edit**

In your case, you should save the image name in `radiobtn4:` and restore in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Ex:

```
- (void)radiobtn4:(UIButton *)sender{
  ....

    if(sender.tag==1){
       ...
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageName forKey:@"selected_image1"];
    }
 }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"selected_image1"];]
         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    ...
}
```

Comment: were should i add this

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the selected state of each entry in your table into your data model. The other poster suggested several different way to save that data.

How are you saving the other information that you display in your table view? I suggest you add a field into your current data for a cell telling you which button is selected. Better to keep all the information for each entry together than to create a new structure that you save somewhere else.

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath select the correct button based on that information.

Right now you probably have a problem. If you change the selected button on the top-most cell, scroll down a ways in your table view, then scroll back to the top, the top button probably looses it's selected button state. You may even have problems with cells that scroll into view showing the wrong selected button state. That's because cells get recycled, and you have to fully configure a cell or it may have leftover settings from the last time it was used.

Answer (score -1):

You will do this using following ways, select one of them.
I am recommending  NSUserDefaults if you need only save button status other vise use CoreData

## Using NSUserDefaults

http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tips/storing-data-with-nsuserdefaults/

## Using CoreData

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

## Using Plist Reading/Writhing

## Using web Services